# Cocoapods: Submitted library not expanding. Swift 2

Tags: cocoapods

I am new to submitting to Cocoapods. I am using Xcode 7 and Swift 2. I believe I have done everything right as of uploading my pod. Github is set up. I have a readme file and it displays fine in Github.

However when i go to Cocoapod and look for `XMSegmentedControl` it shows the pod without the ability to expand (and for some reason it thinks it is ObjC instead of Swift). The docs are empty although my code is documented, and the site link just takes me to the github page.

How can I let Cocoapod expand my pod using the Readme?

Find a picture here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGX4s.png

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it finally worked. Did you do something to fix this? Or did it fix itself after some time? I'm seeing the same issue for my pod `FTLinearActivityIndicator`.